# Restore database from .frm and .ibd

Tags: database, mysql

I had a WordPress website running a long while ago. I used WAMP server. Then, I uninstalled WAMP. Today I would like to work again on my website; all that remains of my database is this (I cannot find the backup I once made):

[image]

So, there seem to be some data left.

However, here is what I get in phpMyAdmin:

[image]

It says my tables don't exist (no table were found for wp_db). Is there any way I can restore the database?

Comment: What type of engine did you use? Old MyISAM databases could be restored from those files, most others can not with standard tools.

Comment: Well, I am using MySQL, within a WAMP server. I think I am out of luck...

Comment: You can see the engine type in PhpMyAdmin in the database list.